# Passing parameters to Mysql function

Tags: php, mysql

I have created this function in mysql and the function is not working. The motive is to get highest score from a view containing student scores in each subject, in a class and in a term and a school session. The `subjectid`, `termid`, `sessionid` and `class` will be passed to the function from php. My goal is to have highest score returned.

```
CREATE FUNCTION highestscore (class CHAR(20),subjectid INT, termid AS INT,sessionid INT) 
      RETURNS INT 
   BEGIN
      SELECT Max(total) AS hscore 
      FROM reportsheetsubjectsview 
      WHERE class=class AND subjectid=subjectid 
      AND termid=termid AND sessionid=sessionid
      RETURN hscore;
   END
```

Edited stored procedure version

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE highestscore(IN subjectid INT, IN class VARCHAR(10), IN termid INT, IN sessionid INT, OUT highesttotalscore INT) 
   DETERMINISTIC 
 begin SELECT Max(total) INTO highesttotalscore FROM scoreview WHERE class=class
    AND subjectid=subjectid AND termid=termid AND sessionid=sessionid; 
 end

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any errors? Or is the result not correct?

Comment: I have rewritten the above mysql function using mysql procedure below. It is now outputting but the evaluated value is not correct. It is ignoring the parameterized part. It is returning the highest score in the table (not based on the parameter.

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `highestscore`(IN `subjectid` INT, IN `class` VARCHAR(10), IN `termid` INT, IN `sessionid` INT, OUT `highesttotalscore` INT)
    DETERMINISTIC
begin
SELECT Max(total) INTO highesttotalscore FROM scoreview 
WHERE class=class AND subjectid=subjectid 
AND termid=termid AND sessionid=sessionid;
end

Answer (score 0):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause to your select.

```
SELECT Max(total) AS hscore 
      FROM reportsheetsubjectsview 
      WHERE class=class AND subjectid=subjectid 
      AND termid=termid AND sessionid=sessionid GROUP BY class, subjectid, termid, sessionid
```

Comment: I have edited the procedure with the answer you have given me but I still get the same result.

Comment: @AdelekeAdelani could you edit your question and add a sample of how your data in the table looks, together with what result you want to get from said sample data?